# Complex URL Routing C# MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I have been able to figure pretty much everything I needed to until now. My URLs are getting more complex and I can get them to route and do what I want but I am sure the way I am doing it is wrong and the code I have to do it is very sloppy. A few of the URLs that I have are:

mysite.com/Setup/FieldManager/Client/List
mysite.com/Setup/FieldManager/Client/Add

Basically the layout of the URL I want is Module/SubModule/Type/Event. My problem is that I am having to pass to a Setup controller that calls the Field Manager Action. From here I am having to do a ridiculous switch statement to then "sub manage" routing from here to the other correct actions. My Field Manager action looks like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult FieldManager(string type, string option, string inputType, string values, string label, string varname, string id)
    {
        CheckAuth(false);
        ActionResult theView = null;
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Client":
                switch (option)
                {
                    case "Add":
                        theView = AddClientField();
                        break;
                    case "List":
                        theView = ClientFieldManager();
                        break;
                    case "Save":
                        theView = SaveClientField(inputType, values, label, varname, id);
                        break;
                    default:
                        theView = EditClientField(option);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "Case":
                theView = View("CaseFieldManager");
                break;
            default:
                theView = View("Error");
                break;
        }
        return theView;
    }
```

I am wanting to maintain the same URL that I am using and call the correct controller/action directly without having to reroute the call from one action to another. The current routes that I have setup are below as well.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{type}/{option}",
            new { action = "Index", type = UrlParameter.Optional, option = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Root",
            "",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What I have works it is just too sloppy and I am having to convert types between calls. I am looking for the best way to accomplish why I am trying to do. Would the best way to do this be to making hundreds of specific routes for all my calls or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One improvement might be to map type and option to nullable enum's instead of strings. Or map the modules to MVC areas, subModule to controller, type to action and event to a nullable enum.

Comment: That's just what I needed. I googled around and found these 2 links:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2-areas and  http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc  and was able to do what I wanted to do. Thanks for the help.